# XPages:Saving special character to dojo grid

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

When ever i try to save special character like ä,ö to my DojoGrid which loads and saves data via xe:restService the character get messedup,
When ever i end the grid directly it save ok, but when ever  i work on it in the background and save it, it get messedup.below is the script on my button

```
var args = {
        onComplete: function() {},
        onError: function() { alert('Update error'); }
}
var grid = dijit.byId('#{id:grid}');
var selectedIDs =grid.selection.getSelected();
    var store = dataGrid.store;
    var Index = grid.selection.selectedIndex;
    if(Index != null){
        var curEntry = dataGrid.getItem(Index);

        var nextEntry = dataGrid.getItem(Index-1);
        currentViewIndex =  store.getValue(curEntry,"ViewIndex");
        nextViewIndex =  store.getValue(nextEntry,"ViewIndex");
        store.setValue(curEntry, 'ViewIndex',nextViewIndex);
        store.setValue(nextEntry, 'ViewIndex',currentViewIndex);
        grid.update();
        restService1.save(args)
        XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:gridDiv}",{});
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to uuencode the strings when you work in the background? ä actually is &auml; or &#228;

Comment: No, i did not how could i that?

Comment: JavaScript has a encodeUri() and encodeUriComponent() function. That might work

Comment: do u have any example how that work with XPages or notes document

Comment: That's a browser function. Nothing XPages specific.